# How to check if class X is a nested class in class Y?

Tags: python, inner-classes

I'm currently working on a [CLI abstraction layer](https://github.com/pyTooling/pyTooling.CLIAbstraction), which abstracts CLI programs as classes in Python. Such CLI programs offer a structured way to enable and configure CLI parameters. It helps checking for faulty inputs and generated properly escaped arguments (e.g. adding double quotes).

*Note: The following example is using Git, while in my [target application](https://github.com/edaa-org/pyEDAA.CLITool), it will be commercial tools, that don't offer any Python API or similar.*

**Basic Ideas:**

- An abstraction of tool Git declares a `Git` class, which derives from class `Program`.
  This parent class implements common methods to all programs.
- CLI options are represented as **nested** class definitions on the `Git` class.
- Nested classes are marked with a class-based decorator `CLIOption` derived from `Attribute`
  (see https://github.com/pyTooling/pyAttributes for more details)
- CLI options can be enabled / modified via indexed syntax.
- An instance of `Git` is used to enabled / configure CLI parameters and helps to assemble a list of correctly encoded strings that can be used e.g. in `subprocess.Popen(...)`

```py
tool = Git()
tool[tool.FlagVersion] = True

print(tool.ToArgumentList())
```

**Some Python Code:**

```py
from pyAttributes import Attribute

class CLIOption(Attribute): ...   # see pyAttributes for more details

class Argument:
  _name: ClassVar[str]

  def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, name: str = "", **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)
    cls._name = name

class FlagArgument(Argument): ...

class CommandArgument(Argument): ...

class Program:
  __cliOptions__: Dict[Type[Argument], Optional[Argument]]

  def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
    """Hook into subclass creation to register all marked CLI options in ``__cliOptions__``.
    super().__init_subclass__(*args, **kwargs)

    # get all marked options and 
    cls.__cliOptions__ = {}
    for option in CLIOption.GetClasses():
      cls.__cliOptions__[option] = None

class Git(Program):
  @CLIOption()
  class FlagVersion(FlagArgument, name="--version"): ...

  @CLIOption()
  class FlagHelp(FlagArgument, name="--help"): ...

  @CLIOption()
  class CmdCommit(CommandArgument, name="commit"): ...
```

**Observations:**

- As [@martineau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/355230/martineau) pointed out in a comment, the CLIOption decorator has no access to the outer scope. So the scope can't be annotated to the nested classes.
- The nested classes are used because of some nice effects in Python not demonstrated here. Also to keep their scope local to a program. Imagine there might be multiple programs offering a `FlagVersion` flag. Some as `-v`, but others as `--version`.

**Primary Questions:**

1. How can I check if class `FlagVersion` is a nested class of class `Git`?

**What I investigated so far:**

- There is no helper function to achieve this goal like functions `isinstance(...)` or `issubclass(...)` are offering.
- While root-level classes have a `__module__` reference to the outer scope, nested classes have no "pointer" to the next outer scope.
- Actually, nested classes have the same `__module__` values.
  Which makes sense.
- A class' `__qualname__` includes the names of parent classes.
  Unfortunately this is a string like `Git.FlagVersion`

So I see a possible "ugly" solution using `__qualname__` and string operations to check if a class is nested and if it's nested in a certain outer scope.

**Algorithm:**

- Assemble fully qualified name from `__module__` and `__qualname__`.
- Check element by element from left to right for matches.

This gets even more complicated if one nested class is defined in a parent class and another nested class is defined in a derived class. Then I also need to look into MRO ... oOo

**Secondary Questions:**

1. Is there a better way than using string operations?
2. Shouldn't Pythons [data model](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html) offer a better way to get this information?

Comment: Since you're decorating these nested classes with `@CLIOption()` anyway, why not write a custom decorator which calls `CLIOption` but also tags the class somehow (e.g. set `cls._is_nested = True`)?

Comment: Nested classes aren't terribly useful in Python — they get no special access to the class containing them. At best they are a way to put a class in the namespace of the one containing them — but doing that also make accessing them more work.

Comment: Bit ugly but you could see if the nested class is contained in the containing classes vars? `nested_class in vars(containing_class).values()`

Comment: @kaya3: One might be able to set a flag to some constant value like `cls._is_nested = True`, but generally speaking a decorator can't determine what the outer class of the nested class is.

Comment: @martineau yes it's used for keeping the scope local. Imaging there might be multiple programs abstracted like this. All of them might have a `FlagVersion` CLI option. Some as `-v` others as `--version`.

Comment: @Paebbels: I've simply been trying to make the point that implementing this with nested classes in Python isn't a good approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the proposed approaches by iterating `__dict__` works quite good.

So this was the first solution developed based on the given ideas:

```py
def isnestedclass(cls: Type, scope: Type) -> bool:
    for memberName in scope.__dict__:
        member = getattr(scope, memberName)
        if type(member) is type:
            if cls is member:
                return True

    return False
```

That solution doesn't work on members inherited from parent classes.
So I extended it with searching through the inheritance graph via `mro()`.

This is my current and final solution for a `isnestedclass` helper function.

```py
def isnestedclass(cls: Type, scope: Type) -> bool:
    for mroClass in scope.mro():
        for memberName in mroClass.__dict__:
            member = getattr(mroClass, memberName)
            if type(member) is type:
                if cls is member:
                    return True

    return False
```

The function is available within the [pyTooling](https://pypi.org/project/pyTooling/) package.

Answer (score 1):

Because I don’t understand English very well, I understand by translating is that you need to find out how to get the embedded class decorated by `CLIOption` in the subclass of `Program` (`Git` here). If so, the following methods may help you.

I read some codes of some `pyAttributes`

```
from pyAttributes import Attribute

class Program(object):
    __cliOptions__: Dict[Type[Argument], Optional[Argument]]

    def __init_subclass__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        cls.__cliOptions__ = {}
        for obj in cls.__dict__.values():
            if hasattr(obj, Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__):
                print(obj)
        # for option in CLIOption.GetClasses():
        #     cls.__cliOptions__[option] = None


class Git(Program):
    a = 1
    b = 2

    @CLIOption()
    class FlagVersion(FlagArgument, name="--version"):
        ...

    @CLIOption()
    class FlagHelp(FlagArgument, name="--help"):
        ...
```

Of course, the above can’t work directly. Later I found that there was of course an error in the `Attribute._AppendAttribute` method, as follows, I modified it

```
class CLIOption(Attribute):
    ...  # see pyAttributes for more details

    @staticmethod
    def _AppendAttribute(func: Callable, attribute: 'Attribute') -> None:
        # inherit attributes and prepend myself or create a new attributes list
        if Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__ in func.__dict__:
            func.__dict__[Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__].insert(0, attribute)
        else:
            # The original func.__setattr__(Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__, [attribute]) has an error
            # Because __setattr__ of class FlagVersion is object.__setattr__

            setattr(func, Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__, [attribute])
            # or object.__setattr__(func, Attribute.__AttributesMemberName__, [attribute])
```

Comment: I also found the problem with `__setattr__` vs. `setattr(...)`. This will be fixed in a new release of pyAttributes (written by me). From comments above, I also followed the approach of iterating `cls.__dict__`. Checking via `hasattr` is a smart move to reduce the number if processed elements in the iteration. I have pushed my solution called [isnestedclass(cls, scope)](https://github.com/pyTooling/pyTooling/blob/dev/pyTooling/Common/__init__.py?ts=2#L59) to GitHub. I'll think about using either `CLIOptions.GetClasses(scope=cls)` or your direct iteration and checking `__dict__` for attributes.